# Counting and knowing what rows are displayed using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I have a table wherein the rows are of different height but are divisible by a certain value. If I scroll down to the middle of the table, is there a way that I will know what rows are displayed and how many are there?

Comment: you can by knowing the _scroll_ position of the page, the _offset_ position of the table, and the _height_ of the _viewport_ ...

Comment: yes. you are right. additional item might be the height of the row. thanks.

Comment: you already mentioned that, so I didn't feel the need to :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work. I haven't had a chance to test it yet. I will try and put a fiddle up in a bit.

I would use this with a throttle on the scroll trigger if you are going to implement it in live, otherwise it would be very intensive for your page to handle.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var rows = $('.my-table tr');
    var range = 100;

    rows.each(function () {
        var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top;
        if (offsetTop - top >= 0 && offsetTop - top <= range) {
            console.log("This is the row at the top of the page");
    });


});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of range?

Comment: Just because if you are throttling, it is not always possible to hit an exact pixel. Its there as a safety net to ensure the row is found. It could probably be reduced to about 10 pixels, depending on how you implement the throttle.